# Repeatable Blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a bit of JS which will generate buttons based on the data attribute stored in the HTML, which will generate 2 buttons:

1. Plus Button to add a repeatable block(Will/should only display a plus button if there is only one block)
2. A minus button to remove the repeatable field(will/should show when there is more than one blocks)

Thing is, I have the buttons working fine, but when I added the event handlers for them to do as I ask, and click on them nothing happens, am not sure why and hopefully you can point me in the right direction.

Regards!

P.S jQuery Code

```
    $('.glyphicon-plus-sign').on("click", function () {
        prevInput = $(this).prev('input');
        count = $(prevInput).attr('data-count');
        countIncremented = count++;
        br = '<br/><br/>';
        inputElement = '<input type="' + $(prevInput).attr("type") + '" name="' + $(prevInput).attr("name") + countIncremented + '" data-count="' + countIncremented + '"/>';
        $(br + inputElement + plusMinusButtons).insertAfter('.' + $(prevInput).attr("name") + ':last');
    });
    $('.glyphicon-minus-sign').on("click", function () {
        prevInput = $(this).prev('input');
        $(this).remove(prevInput).remove(this);
    });
    $("button").click(function () {
        console.log("here");
        x = $('#form').serializeArray();
        $.each(x, function (i, field) {
            console.log(field.name + ":" + field.value + " ");
});
```

Comment: Do you see any error messages in your javascript console?

Comment: Please provide only minimalistic code which can replicate your issue. BTW, if this condition is not reached `$(this).attr('data-maxOccurs') != 1` then you are not binding any event because elements are not added to the DOM.

Comment: Dont know why I got down voted, if you down vote me at least tell me why so I avoid in the future.

Comment: Cant Fiddle on my current network

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PeSa8/4/)  as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I currently have a bit of JS which will generate buttons

**Dynamically adding buttons means you have to approach events a little differently**. You need to do the following:

```
$('body').on("click", '.glyphicon-minus-sign', function () {
    ...
}

$('body').on("click", '.glyphicon-plus-sign', function () {
    ...
}
```

Essentially, you are now listening to clicks on the body element, instead of the actual buttons (which might not actually exist yet). Any other statically created buttons aren't affected.

Comment: I see, still nothing happening :( I think the logic must be wrong within the functions for the buttons? I cant seem to locate the issue, it seems correct to me

Comment: Confirm with your console to see if the buttons are correctly setup (class should be correct etc). Let me know how that goes. Use a quick console.log('here') kinda statement in the listeners if you are unsure.

Comment: Am getting no issues at all in the console the buttons are correctly setup, and display in HTML as <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign">, just nothing happens when I click the object

Comment: ah. So the class is on the span? And is the button in the span element? so like is it `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"><button ... /></span>`?

Comment: <span><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>Yeah it is, I tried it as just a button as well, it just takes me to the top of the page and doesn't replicate the block

Comment: Wait which one is it? You've posted two different things there. Feel free to use JSfiddle to show me the whole thing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52117/discussion-between-niall-and-studento919)